# Массив, как сложить все положительные числа, которые стоят между 2-мя отрицательными?

Tags: pascal

Есть массив чисел. Сложить все положительные числа, которые стоят между 2-мя отрицательными.

Comment: Что сделали? Что не получилось?

Comment: Да что-то с логикой натупил=) У меня туго с паскалем) Другие языки норм, а вот паскаль прошел каким-то образом мимо меня)

Comment: Напишите на любом языке -  и вам помогут перевести в паскаль

Comment: А в чём проблема то? Ищите в цикле первое отрицательное число, если оно есть, то складывайте до второго или до тех пор, пока цикл не дойдёт до конца. Если в цонце неотрицательное число (или отрицателиных чисел вообще нет), то сумма равна нулю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

простенький алгоритм:

```
 // определяем переменные
 var
  Array1: array [0..9] of integer;   // собственно массив
  i, z: integer;  // переменная для цикла и переменная для суммирования
  add: boolean;  // признак сложения
 begin
  add:= False;  // отменяем сложение чисел
  z:= 0;        // обнуляем результат

  // пробегаем массив
  for I := 0 to 9 do
   if Array1[i] < 0 then         // если число меньше нуля, то
    begin                        // смотрим на признак сложения
     if Add = False then         // если нельзя складывать, то
      begin
        Add:= True;              // разрешаем
      end
     else                        // если можно складывать, то
      Add:= False;               // запрещаем
    end
  else                           // если число больше нуля, то
   if Add = True then            // если сложение разрешено, то
    z:= z + Array1[i];           // складываем
```

PS. признак сложения тут нужен для следующего:
в массиве: -2  1  -2  1  -2  1  -2
при выключенном признаке сложения отрицательные числа будут использоваться только один раз, т.е. в данном случае результатом будет число 2... (-2 1 -2) 1 (-2 1 -2)

при включенном будет следующее: (-2  1  -2) (-2  1  -2) (-2  1  -2), и результат будет 3

Алгоритм работает независимо от положения отрицательных и положительных чисел

Answer (score 1):

По условию задачи, нам нужно знать правый отрицательный и левый отрицательный

И посчитать между ними все положительные

```
   var
     arr: array [0..9] of integer;   //массив
     i, s, r, l:integer;
   begin
     fillchar(arr,sizeof(arr),0); //зануляем весь массив (необязательно, если он заполняется полностью)
     for i := 0 to 9 do //считываем числа
     read(arr[i]);

     s:= 0;        //обнуляем результат

     for r := 9 downto 0 do //нашли правую границу
     if (arr[r] < 0) then break;

     for l := 0 to 9 do //нашли левую границу
     if (arr[l] < 0) then break;

     // пробегаем массив от левого до правого отрицательного
     for i := l to r do
     if arr[i] > 0 then inc(s,arr[i]); //суммируем положительные

     write(s);
   end.
```

Comment: А Вам не приходило в голову, что таких "границ" может быть несколько, как и блоков положительных чисел между отрицательными. И потом, про размер массива в задаче ничего не сказано. Так что нужно писать в расчета на любой размер и любую его структуру.

Comment: И что?

-2 1 1 1 -2 1 1 1 -2

все однерки попадают под условие, так как слева и справа от них есть 

отрицательные числа

не глупите

Comment: Попробую более общий вариант

1 1 -1 2 2 -2 3 -3 4 4

под условие попадают 2 2 3
так как справа и слева от них есть отрицательные -> они стоят между ними

если добавим в конец массива -5 к примеру то под условие попадут ещё и 4 4

Comment: Алгоритм - верный) чего все недовольны?)

Comment: Видимо все извратом любят заниматься, а не читать задачу :)

Comment: Да, все правильно, сперва не понял. Поставил законный +1

Answer (score 0):

Написал функцию для С/С++. Может, кому будет полезна

```
int sum_pos (const int * arr, int size) {
    int res = 0, n = 0, restmp;
    size-=2;
    do {
        if (n >= size) return res;  
    } while (arr [n++] >= 0);

    for (; n <size ;n++) {
        if (arr[n] < 0) continue;
        restmp = arr[n];
        while ( arr[++n] >= 0 ) {
           if (n > size) return res; 
           restmp += arr[n];
        }
        res += restmp;
    }
    return res;     
}
```